# Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource - only in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox

I am developing a page on localhost using a docker image on Ubuntu since month.
Today, I run `npm update buefy` and `npm run prod` (may be the first time I used npm since I have the docker container) and then in Firefox, all my js resources suddenly failed to load.

Here some examples from the inspection tool:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:8005/js/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js ("script-src").

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js ("script-src").

This only happens in Firefox in normal mode.
The browser can load the resources in Firefox when I am in incognito mode.
The resources can be loaded without any problems in Chrome in any mode.
I have removed cookies for `localhost` but the problem still persists.

What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally had [Disable JS](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/disable-javascript/) plugin set to active in Firefox. That is why it worked in Chrome and in incognito mode on Firefox.